# how to maintain a plist so you dont lose your values

Tags: iphone, ios, plist

I have a plist which I read from my bundle into a new plist object that I put in the root directory for reading and writing. My question is what do I do with this or what dose the application do when its quit, and better yet what happens when the app is killed from the "multi task" menu from ios.

Also is there a way to save this plist to memory/the bundle for future use when the application is used again.

My code is as follows for refrence.

Here is my .h

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

    @interface EngineProperties : NSObject {

    NSString *signature;
    NSNumber *version;
    NSNumber *request;
    NSNumber *dataVersion;
    NSMutableDictionary *cacheValue;
    //cachevalue Items
    NSNumber *man;
    NSNumber *mod;
    NSNumber *sub;

    }

    @property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *signature;
    @property (copy, nonatomic) NSNumber *version;
    @property (copy, nonatomic) NSNumber *request;
    @property (copy, nonatomic) NSNumber *dataVersion;
    @property (copy, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *cacheValue;
    //cachevalue Items
    @property (copy, nonatomic) NSNumber *man;
    @property (copy, nonatomic) NSNumber *mod;
    @property (copy, nonatomic) NSNumber *sub;



    //Singletton
+ (id)sharedManager;
    - (void) saveData:(NSString *)methodName signature:(NSString *)pSignature Version:(NSNumber *)pVersion request:(NSNumber *)rNumber dataVersion:(NSNumber *)dvReturned cacheValue:(NSNumber *)cValue;

    @end
```

and Here is my .m

```
 #import "EngineProperties.h"

static EnginePropertiesController *sharedMyManager = nil;

    @implementation EngineProperties

    @synthesize signature;
    @synthesize version;
    @synthesize request;
    @synthesize dataVersion;
    @synthesize cacheValue;

    @synthesize man;
    @synthesize mod;
    @synthesize sub;



    #pragma mark Singleton Methods
+ (id)sharedManager {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (sharedMyManager == nil)
            sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
    }
    return sharedMyManager;
}
- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {

        // Data.plist code
        // get paths from root direcory
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        // get documents path
        NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        // get the path to our Data/plist file
        NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"EngineProperties.plist"];

        // check to see if Data.plist exists in documents
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath])
        {
            // if not in documents, get property list from main bundle
            plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"EngineProperties" ofType:@"plist"];
        }

        // read property list into memory as an NSData object
        NSData *plistXML = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:plistPath];
        NSString *errorDesc = nil;
        NSPropertyListFormat format;
        // convert static property liost into dictionary object
        NSDictionary *tempRoot = (NSMutableDictionary *)[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:plistXML mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves format:&format errorDescription:&errorDesc];
        if (!tempRoot)
        {
            NSLog(@"Error reading plist: %@, format: %d", errorDesc, format);
        }
        // assign values
        self.signature = [tempRoot objectForKey:@"Signature"];
        self.version = [tempRoot objectForKey:@"Version"];
        self.request = [tempRoot objectForKey:@"Request"];
        self.dataVersion = [tempRoot objectForKey:@"Data Version"];

        man = [cacheValue objectForKey:@"Man"];
        mod = [cacheValue objectForKey:@"Mod"];
        sub = [cacheValue objectForKey:@"SubMod"];

        cacheValue = [tempRoot objectForKey:@"Cache Value"];
    }


    - (void) saveData:(NSString *)methodName signature:(NSString *)pSignature Version:(NSNumber *)pVersion request:(NSNumber *)rNumber dataVersion:(NSNumber *)dvReturned cacheValue:(NSNumber *)cValue;
    {
        // get paths from root direcory
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        // get documents path
        NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        // get the path to our Data/plist file
        NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"EngineProperties.plist"];

        // set the variables to the values in the text fields
        self.signature = pSignature;
        self.version = pVersion;
        self.request = rNumber;
        self.dataVersion = dvReturned;

        //do some if statment stuff here to put the cache in the right place or what have you.
        if (methodName == @"manufacturers")
        {
            self.man = cValue; 
        }
        else if (methodName == @"models")
        {
            self.mod = cValue;
        }
        else if (methodName == @"subMod")
        {
            self.sub = cValue;
        }

        self.cacheValue = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                           man, @"Manufacturers",
                           mod, @"Models",
                           sub, @"SubModels", nil];


        NSDictionary *plistDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   signature, @"Signature",
                                   version, @"Version",
                                   request, @"Request",
                                   dataVersion, @"Data Version",
                                   cacheValue, @"Cache Value", nil];



        NSString *error = nil;
        // create NSData from dictionary
        NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:plistDict format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:&error];

        // check is plistData exists
        if(plistData)
        {
            // write plistData to our Data.plist file
            [plistData writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];

            NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:plistData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            //        NSLog(@"%@", myString);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Error in saveData: %@", error);
            //        [error release];
        }
    }


    @end
```

Answer (score 0):

It honestly depends on how frequently you'll be asking for and changing the plist's values.  For instance, my app only needed to retrieve it once, then write it a few times (nothing much), so all of my saving code was at the end of said particular method.

However, if your plist is live (constant value changes), keeping a reference to the data you wish to save that is accessible from the AppDelegate is recommended.  That way, you can simply call: `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:` on -`applicationDidResignActive` and save your plist data.

(Note, if the user is fast enough to kill your app before it saves completely (big if), there are no guarantees as to the integrity of your plist).

Comment: right. I get what your saying and that helpfull. But another concern I have is actually saving the data.. when I closed the application on my SDK and checked the bundle.. my plist was empty. I am woundering how long dose the plist last for? (when will it be deleted?) i.e. when the user closes it, deletes the multi task instance or deletes the app of his/her phone? Thank you for your answer btw.

Comment: So long as you use -beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:, your objects should stick around.  If your plist is empty, then you aren't doing something right, whether that be encoding or object handling.

Comment: well my plist is empty because thats my plist template which is placed in the bundle (only reading no writing), which I copy into my documents root for reading/writing.. its just im not sure what to do with the plist I have now created in my root document folder.. or how long it lasts for etc... I am going to read up that method you just listed.

Answer (score 0):

follow the blow link in that link they provided the code also. How to Write/Read data to .plist file.

[Plist](http://ipgames.wordpress.com/tutorials/writeread-data-to-plist-file/)

Comment: Yep, I have pretty much done what this guy is talking about. However I am more interested about how to preserve my values if the app is deleted from the multitasking menu? what happens to the plist values then?>

Comment: if u deleted from the multitasking menu the plist values cannot be deleted.If u r app deleted from the simulator/device then add values can be deleted from the plist other wise until values cannot be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can quickly and easily save plists to NSUserDefaults

Check out this quick tutorial:

http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSUserDefaults

Comment: okay so I have been looking into this, and I have one question. 
Do you save plists into NSUserDefaults.. or do you save values into NSUserDefaults that would be alot like the structure of your plist..

Comment: You can _only_ save property lists to NSUserDefaults.

Comment: For more clarification, NSUserDefaults acts like an NSDictionary, where all of the values are property lists or property list elements (such as NSStrings)